# Retrieving Stock Data From Morningstart

Tags: python

I am relatively new to Python. I am trying to automate retrieving data from the following URL:

https://lt.morningstar.com/gco59km9k1/snapshot/default.aspx?tab=7&Id=F00000NMH9&ClientFund=0&CurrencyId=CAD

The interactive chart has a "Chart Settings" button, which leads to a drop down menu with the "Print/Export" option which leads the "Export to Excel" link. I have been downloading the excel sheet manually and then reading with Python using the following code.

Stock = pd.read_excel('MorningstarIWT_ExcelExport.xlsx')

I'd appreciate any pointers towards automating this procedure.

Comment: Do you want to save the data in excel? or do you just want to use it and the forget about it? In both cases try mimicking the js code written in the website. (you can find it by inspecting the button element and tracking its click event, In your case its the function which starts with "function(c){c=[];" at  https://lt.morningstar.com/js/technicalchart.min.js).

Comment: Hi atanay. I want to use the data and save it in a variable, I don't need to save it in excel. Can you provide additional details as to how to "mimic the js code"?  I am not sure how to do that. Thanks

Comment: "mimic" in the sense of the way they format the data (names of rows, columns, order and stuff). In order to obtain the data you can use something like requests (a python library) which will give you the html of the page, then find the data in the html.